# CSS Recreating UL LIs for clickable bullet images

Tags: css

I am trying to create a true/natural CSS UL LI list (no JQuery, Javascript, etc), but I want to hide the list-style-type and use my own images for the bullets. Also, I want the bullets to be hyperlinked; this is why I am not using images within the LI tag. So, I am having trouble with recreating how a true UL LI would be have with indentation, etc. Here is my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/Z5pw4/2/

The 1st screenshot below is how my code currently looks. The 2nd screenshot below that is a hypothetical Photoshopped image of how I would like it to look. I would like to meet these ideas:

1.) The blue boxes need to be fluid

2.) The blue boxes need to sit next to the red box (like the last bullet in my 2nd screenshot)

3.) The bullet images are hyperlinked

4.) All will sit in a DIV (e.g. the yellow DIV) and the contents (LI text) will be fluid

Any ideas on how to fix? I am using a wrapper around each bullet image and bullet text. I am just not sure if I should use float:left, display:inline-block, clear:both; etc, etc.

**Current**

Problems:

- blue boxes are wrapping underneath the red box (I would like them to sit side by side)
- blue boxes are not extending to the full width of the container.

[image]

**My Goal**

[image]

Comment: sorry, but it's really hard to understand what you want to achieve - your question doesn't really match the picture you've added, please rephrase

Comment: You're using ID multiple times in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tomasdev/Z5pw4/9/

If you want the blue background on the bullet side, you can make a bigger image and remove the background position from anchor element.

You should **keep it simple**:

```
<div id="pagebox">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="bullet"><em>My news topic</em></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="bullet">This is a short story</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bullet">This is a longer story, yes it is</a><br></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bullet">This is the longest story, I do declare, don't you agree?</a><br></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
<style>
body,a {color:#fff; }
#pagebox { width:1300px; background:#ccc;  }
#pagebox li { line-height: 1.5em; list-style-type:none; }
#pagebox ul li img, ul li ul li img { vertical-align:text-bottom; }
#pagebox ul li ul{
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
.bullet { 
    background:#FF0000 url('http://images-4.findicons.com/files/icons/1689/splashy/16/bullet_blue.png') no-repeat 2px 5px;
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Won't work if he needs the bullets and text to be different links as in his fiddle.

Comment: @Scott he probably didn't mean that.

Comment: Thank you for the post! This works great, but I wonder if I could add some descriptive text next to the link (that is not hyperlinked) that will also follow the indentation rule that a UL would normally follow. Here is an updated Fiddle of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/Z5pw4/11/

Comment: @webdude77 sure you can. I used the A because I thought you wanted everything linked. Replace it with a div, and then use the anchor inside that div only for the content. It should look like <li><div class="bullet"><a>stuff</a> more stuff</div></li> got it?

Comment: Hi Tom: Your advice worked well. It seems to work well if the image and link text go to the same link. I need to have a unique link on the bullet and another unique link within the same LI that goes to a different hyperlink. How can we make the bullet go to 1 href and the text link go to another a 2nd href? Also, I think I figured out how to have an input checkbox in the same position as my bullet.
http://jsfiddle.net/zenfiddle/Z5pw4/12/

Comment: @webdude77 http://jsfiddle.net/tomasdev/Z5pw4/13/ if you want you can make the whole LI background red... I don't know what you're doing but seems really nasty. Checkboxes with 2 anchors that points to different locations... hmmm I recommend you try to figure out in a better way what you are trying to approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those internal divs.... You can simply apply a class to the anchor for the bullet images. Also be aware, you can't assign the same ID to multiple items. Only one ID per page. No id should appear multiple times.

Updated fiddle -------> [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5pw4/7/)

Comment: This seems like a pretty good solution. It doesn't quite work for me because the absolute and relative positioning seems to break other formatting and layout on the page (nothing else on the page uses relative or absolute).